# How do I get VLOOKUP to return all results not just one (using formula not auto-filter)

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table full of several orders and the dates. On another page i want to be able to type in a date and for all orders to show from that date, like a VLOOKUP. But, a VLOOKUP would only display one of the orders or say error. I know i can filter my tables but i have hundreds of dates so i want to be able to just type it and for all orders from that date to show. Is that possible?

I have tried several tables and even pivot tables but none has worked

Answer (score 1):

The [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function can do that.

See example below. You might need to manually format the result columns though.

[image]

Comment: one note: OP tagged 2010 and 2016, neither have FILTER.

Answer (score 1):

Answer without FILTER:

Insert a helper column at column A in the source sheet, from A2:

```
=IF(filterdate = datecolumn, A1+1, A1)
```

Now do a VLOOKUP by row number in the second sheet:

```
= VLOOKUP(ROW(), SHEET1!$A$2:$H$1000, datecolumn number, FALSE)
```

It is possible to use FILTER in Excel 365 or array formulae (in priop versions) to do this without a helper column. The difference between the array formula method and this helper column method is that you trade floor space (cell storage) for complexity/number of calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. It acts very much like the more recent `FILTER()` does:

```
=INDEX(SourceTable,    LARGE(  (FilterColumn = FilterValue) * (ROW(SourceTable)-1),  ROW(  INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTIF(FilterColumn,"="&FilterValue)  )  )),     {1,2})
```

`FilterColumn = FilterValue` compares the values in your source's date column against the value you are searching it for. It produces an array of TRUE/FALSE values.

`ROW(SourceTable)-1` generates the row position inside the source table with the "-1" reducing the value by 1 for the assumption of a one row high set of column headers. You'd change that to suit, 0 for no headers, >1 for multi-line headers. Essentially it is precisely what `MATCH()` would do given a range address to find a match in, but does it for each row as needed instead of returning a single value, and also, needing no actual value to match.

They are multiplied for two reasons:  1) Because multiplying, usually by 1 if just one of these arrays, will force Excel to change the array of TRUE/FALSE's into an array of 1/0's, and 2) Because that forced 1/0 array can then be multiplied by the array of row numbers produced by that `ROW(SourceTable)-1` calculation. You want to do that so the row numbers in it for rows you do not want change to 0's rather than discrete values. The rows you DO want stay as the original row numbers they were.

So, now your formula has an array of many 0's and some non-zero numbers. Something like `{0,0,0,0,0,6,7,0,0,10,0,12}`. That'd be unfortunate if you could not move beyond it because, while the output WOULD be just the rows you need, they could be anywhere in the hundreds of rows you don't need. Like row 12 on your output page and then 406 blank rows, then two more. Not too useful if you want something presented to you rather than having to do something like copying and pasting as values, sorting to float them all to the top, and going from there. Very old school and very not really what it seems you'd like.

Interestingly though, while text functions cannot usefully (or at all) edit the array because they cannot make empty elements go away leaving only interesting elements... they replace empty items with empty items... but some functions can do what is needed. Their logic is they are extracting the interesting elements into a new array and dumping the whole original array rather than trying to work on the original and move it onward, edited, in the formula.

`LARGE()` is used here because it can find the "Xth" largest element of a range/array while `MAX()` can only find "the" largest. And it can take an array constant as its parameter for the "X" in "Xth" largest. That means you can tell it to take MORE than just one value. You could just type such an array constant (it would look like, say, `{14,15,16,22}` if you wanted the 14th, 15th, 16th, and 22nd largest elements), but you can also use functions to create it.

Nowadays we'd use `SEQUENCE()` if at all possible, but -2010 and -2016 versions did not have that. Their way, the "OG" way, to create such an array was to use the `ROW()` function. An example that would get an array of values from 1 to 400 would be:

```
=ROW(1:400)
```

The formula uses that idea and builds a string like that. Actually, like the "1:400" part, and wraps it with `INDIRECT()` so it can become recognizable as a parameter to `ROW()` in Excel's "mind." Why build a string? Because in it you can fit a counting function, `COUNTIF()`, that can count the not-empty ones. So then the sequence you get will be the largest down to that many-th:  in short, you collect all the not-empty ones into the new array. Good for business!

So, the outer `INDEX()` function has its range address, or Named Range. All this work gave it its Row/s parameter, and you just need the Column/s parameter.

Nothing fancy to that. Since the columns you need could be very hodge-podge, just type an array constant. In my sample work for writing this formula, I used two columns and collected both. That gives the `{1,2}` you see at the end of the formula. If you had eight columns and wanted just the first and all the even ones, you'd type `{1,2,4,6,8}` instead. As a side note, you might not only leave columns out like that does, but have them out of order, or even some more than once (like `{3,3,7,5,1,2,3,7,5,5,5,2}` if you wanted).

Just one thing left to do. Formatting. But that's easy, at least in my Excel-today version. I believe it is the same a fair ways back in Excel, so I shall present it and let you find out.

Select (highlight) one row's cells in the columns you want. So in the example just above, maybe you pick row 14 and highlight cells A14, B14, D14, F14, and H14. Copy them to the Clipboard. Go to where your new table is and select/highlight the five columns that make it up. `Paste|Special|Formats` any of the various ways to do that. Your columns are formatted. Excel ignores the empty, not-selected, cells when doing the paste so the five cells with cells between them become a single set of five "contiguous" cells for the paste. Easy Peasey.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filter function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

And Advanced filter feature can also get the result: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b